# Using Socket.IO in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, socket.io

I'm trying to read a Socket.IO stream from Wikimedia sites.  There is sample code for various languages, but I need to get this working in C#

The source link is here:

https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/RCStream

And here is the JavaScript implementation.

```
// Requires socket.io-client 0.9.x:
// browser code can load a minified Socket.IO JavaScript library;
// standalone code can install via 'npm install socket.io-client@0.9.1'.

var io = require( 'socket.io-client' );
var socket = io.connect( 'stream.wikimedia.org/rc' );

socket.on( 'connect', function () {
     socket.emit( 'subscribe', 'commons.wikimedia.org' );
} );

socket.on( 'change', function ( data ) {
    console.log( data.title );
} );
```

I've tried about 3 or so .NET versions of socket.io and have been unable to get a connection.  The closest I've come is getting an "invalid endpoint" error message.  I think part of the problem is some of the libraries I was using (from Nuget and other places) where different versions of socket.io 0.9.x

I was hoping someone here could help me find a way of getting this working in C#.  I've spent about 4 hours to no avail.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve real-time server/client communication with .NET, you might want to look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on a C# client for Socket.IO like [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) or [SocketIO4net](http://socketio4net.codeplex.com/) so your code would be as simple as in JS.

```
var socket = IO.Socket("http://stream.wikimedia.org/rc");
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
    socket.Emit("hi");
});

socket.On("connect", (data) =>
{
    socket.Emit("subscribe", "commons.wikimedia.org");
});

socket.On("change", (data) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.title);
});
```

Comment: Tried both of those clients.  Did this actually work for you?  The "change" event is never fired for me.